# How can I send an event-specific PDF certificate to participants via email?

Tags: tokens, civirules

Using Civirules and the PDF Creation API extension I can send an email with an attached PDF containing tokenised content to a contact based on a specified trigger and conditions.

What I want to do is be able to send an email to an event participant (triggered by the change in their participant status) with an attached PDF that contains data pulled from both default and custom fields for that given event. Do-able? Feels like it should be, but when setting up the message template for the email and the PDF I don't know how I could specify suitable tokens for the event?

Comment: My suggestion was going to be "if you go Find Participants, and then Actions > PDF Letter, then you can create a template with Participant tokens" but i checked on dmaster.demo and i don't see any